# Does $H^2(X_{Zar},\mathcal{O}_X^\times)=0$ for $X$ a regular scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a regular Noetherian scheme. I read in Milne's book on Etale Cohomology that this implies that $H^2(X_{Zar},\mathcal{O}_X^\times)=0$. Can anyone explain the proof of this fact or give a reference to the proof?

Comment: Consider posting on MathOverflow for a change of getting an answer from Mline himself: https://mathoverflow.net/users/930/js-milne

Comment: (Etale cohomology still scares me a bit...)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2610807/second-zariski-cohomology-of-the-multiplicative-group/2612039#2612039 (Note that $\mathbb{G}_m$ is just another name for $\mathcal{O}_X^{\times}$)